# How to convert PDF binary parts into ASCII/ANSI so I can look at it in a text editor?

Tags: pdf, binaryfiles

Most PDFs contain lots of binary looking parts in between some ASCII. But I remember also having seen PDFs where such binary parts by and large were absent, and one could open them in a text editor to study their structure.

Is there a trick, tool, or command that will convert binary PDF parts to ASCII/ANSI? (Preferably "free as in beer" or even "free as in liberty")

Answer (score 32, accepted):

***[Updated 2014-10-15]***

### Using Ghostscript

Ghostscript has a small utility program written in PostScript in its source code repository. It's called `pdfinflt.ps`. If you are lucky, it may already slumber in a 'toolbin' subdirectory of your Ghostscript installation location. Otherwise, get it here:

- http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/trunk/gs/toolbin/pdfinflt.ps

Now run it together with your targeted input PDF through the Ghostscript interpreter:

```
gswin32c.exe -- c:/path/to/pdfinflt.ps your-input.pdf deflated-output.pdf
```

`pdfinflt.ps` will (try to) expand all 'streams' contained in the PDF which use the following compression filters/methods: `/FlateDecode`, `/LZWDecode`, `/ASCII85Decode`, `/ASCIIHexDecode`.

It will not attempt to remove `/RunLengthDecode`, `/CCITTFaxDecode`, `/DCTDecode`, `/JBIG2Decode` and `/JPXDecode`. (Compressed/binary fonts will also pass unchanged into the output PDF.)

If you are in an adventurous mood, you may dare to uncomment those lines in the utility which disable `/RunLengthDecode`, `/DCTDecode` and `CCITTFaxDecode` and see if it still works...

---

### Using `qpdf`

Another useful tool to transform a PDF into an internal format that enables text editor access is **[`qpdf`](http://qpdf.sf.net/)**. It is a *"command-line program that does structural, content-preserving transformations on PDF files"*.

**Example usage:**

```
 qpdf                                  \
   --qdf                               \
   --object-streams=disable            \
     input-with-compressed-objects.pdf \
     output-with-expanded-objects.pdf
```

1. The output of the `QDF`-mode enforced by the `--qdf` switch organizes and re-orders the objects neatly. It adds comments to track the original object IDs and page content streams. All object dictionaries are written into a "normalized" standard format for easier parsing.
2. The `--object-streams=disable` causes the extraction of (otherwise not recognizable) individual objects that are compressed into another object's stream data.

---

#### Using `mutool`

[Artifex](http://www.artifex.com/), the creators of [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/), offer another under a Free and Open Source Software license available tool: **[`MuPDF`](http://www.mupdf.com/)**.

MuPDF comes with a command line tool, **`mutool`**, which also can expand compressed PDF object streams:

```
 mutool        \
    clean      \
   -d          \
   -a          \
    input.pdf  \
    output.pdf \
    4,7,8,9
```

1. **`clean`**: re-writes the PDF;
2. **`-d`**: de-compresses all streams;
3. **`-a`**: ASCIIhex encodes all binary streams;
4. **`4,7,8,9`**: selects pages 4, 7, 8 and 9 for inclusion in `output.pdf`.

### Using `pdftk`

Last, here is how to use the `pdtk` tool to uncompress PDF object's streams:

```
pdftk your-input.pdf cat output uncompressed-output.pdf uncompress
```

Note the final `uncompress` word in the command line.

---

### Pick your favorite

All above tools are available for Linux, Mac OSX, Unix and Windows.

My own favorite is **`QPDF`** for most practical cases.

However, you should make your own experiments and compare the (different) output of each of the suggested tools. Then make your own pick.

Comment: Thank you ... this works for me at least in parts. I can now better poke at all these *obj 1 0 R* parts... trying to understand that stuff better.

Comment: Wish I could recommend this answer ten times.  My favorite application is to fix OCR errors in the hidden (copy-pastable) text behind scanned documents: convert to ascii with pdftk uncompress, find and fix the typos with the editor, then (if desired) compress again.

Comment: @SilvioLevy: Well, for a start you could upvote it at least *once*. And in lieu of not being allowed multiple votes for the same answer, you could search ***[my complete list of PDF-related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A359307+%5Bpdf%5D)*** and see if you find 9 other ones you deem worth of upvoting :-)

Comment: @KurtPeifle Why do you think I have not upvoted it?  Thanks for your list of answers; I will definitely look at it when I have the leisure. Thank you for your contributions.

Comment: @SilvioLevy: I just noticed that around the time of your comment there was no upvote for this answer. In fact, there was no upvote for this answer since even a few months. Sometimes, newbie StackExchanges users do not (yet) know how its sites work... No bad feelings.

Comment: That's because I tried to upvote it and was told that I couldn't upvote twice -- apparently I'd seen this answer in the past and liked it.  Hence my comment.  (As a matter of fact I just looked it up in my browser history: it was on March 27 around 9PM pacific time (March 28 if you're in Europe).  Maybe you see an upvote then? ;-)

Comment: none at all.  I was just curious whether you'd find it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149284/discussion-between-silvio-levy-and-kurt-pfeifle).

Comment: Thank you for this - I'm on mac and was able to install qpdf with homebrew. Thanks!

Comment: Homebrew? Which version did it give you? (*`'pandoc --version'`*)

Comment: @jtlz2: So you liked my answer good enough to add a comment to it... but no *upvote*?